# Text-To-Speech recognition with IVONA TTS

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm developing and app that repeat everything i write inside a editText.
Well i'm using IVONA Text-to-speech in my nexus 5 and so i wrote

```
if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
  int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale ("it", giorgio));
}
```

and as expected it works perfectly; infact it repeats everything with "Giorgio" voice. But if i try to add a button to using the recognition api, i get an error in the log cat:

```
Couldn't retrive ISO 3166 country code for locale: it_GIORGIO...
```

and the the wrong line is exactly `int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale ("it", giorgio));`

so, if i try to add what i say in a textview not works. Is IVONA the problem? How can i solve?

Comment: Can you post the code where you start the recognition please

Comment: i opened a new quest in which there is the code. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299577/speech-recognition-not-works-android