# Speech recognition not works Android

Tags: java, android, textview, text-to-speech

I want display in a `TextView` what I say using the tts engine. I have a `Button`:

```
btnparla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something");

                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(i, VOICE_REC);
                        //txt.setText("");
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.show();
                    }
                }   

            });
```

and then:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (resultCode) {
            case VOICE_REC: {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        ArrayList<String> dico = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                        resultList.setText(dico.get(0));

                    }
                    break;
                }


                }
        }
```

where `resultList` is a `TextView` declared in the `onCreate` `resultList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list);`. The `Button` works but does not save anything in the `TextView`. It does not display what I say. What's wrong?

Comment: Code appears OK, I think it may be something wrong with the declaration of your TextView but I cannot tell. Please show me what that declaration looks like. Also add this code after setText and tell me if the logger comes up with anything: if (matches.size() > 0) {Log.d("MainActivity", matches.get(0))}; If it does, then we know text to speech is working and it must be a textview issue

Comment: In your other question, you said you were creating a custom locale, I assume that is persisting. Try adding i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "it-IT");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter VOICE_REC in `startActivityForResult(i, VOICE_REC);` is the requestCode not the resultCode. Change the switch condition from `switch (resultCode)` to `switch (requestCode)`.

```
    switch (requestCode) {
        case VOICE_REC: {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> dico =  data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                resultList.setText(dico.get(0));

            }
            break;
        }
    }
```